# Encrypted configuration in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

With `web.config` going away, what is the preferred way to store sensitive info (passwords, tokens) in the configurations of a web app built using ASP.NET Core?

Is there a way to automatically get encrypted configuration sections in `appsettings.json`?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

User secrets looks like a good solution for storing passwords, and, generally, application secrets, at least *during development*.

Check the [official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets). You can also review [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31426358/where-should-i-store-the-connection-string-for-the-production-environment-of-my) other SO question.

This is just a way to "hide" your secrets during development process and to avoid disclosing them into the source tree; the Secret Manager tool **does not encrypt the stored secrets** and should not be treated as a trusted store.

If you want to bring an encrypted `appsettings.json` to production, you can do so by building a [custom configuration provider](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html#writing-custom-providers).

For example:

```cs
public class CustomConfigProvider : ConfigurationProvider, IConfigurationSource
{
    public CustomConfigProvider()
    {
    }

    public override void Load()
    {
        Data = UnencryptMyConfiguration();
    }

    private IDictionary<string, string> UnencryptMyConfiguration()
    {
        // do whatever you need to do here, for example load the file and unencrypt key by key
        //Like:
       var configValues = new Dictionary<string, string>
       {
            {"key1", "unencryptedValue1"},
            {"key2", "unencryptedValue2"}
       };
       return configValues;
    }

    private IDictionary<string, string> CreateAndSaveDefaultValues(IDictionary<string, string> defaultDictionary)
    {
        var configValues = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"key1", "encryptedValue1"},
            {"key2", "encryptedValue2"}
        };
        return configValues;                
    }

    public IConfigurationProvider Build(IConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
       return new CustomConfigProvider();
    }
}
```

Define a static class for your extension method:

```cs
public static class CustomConfigProviderExtensions
{              
        public static IConfigurationBuilder AddEncryptedProvider(this IConfigurationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.Add(new CustomConfigProvider());
        }
}
```

And then you can activate it:

```cs
// Set up configuration sources.
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .AddEncryptedProvider()
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
```

Comment: I have same problem. can you complete UnencryptMyConfiguration based on your comment ?(for example load the file and unencrypt key by key)

Comment: I posted a solution below that works for me, a lot simpler and perfect for my needs.

Comment: For the benefit of someone who is extremely new to ASP.NET Core, how would I ultimately access the connection string value in `Startup.ConfigureServices()` in order to pass it into `UseSqlServerStorage()`?

Answer (score 27):

I agree with @CoderSteve that writing a whole new provider is too much work. It also doesn't build on the existing standard JSON architecture. Here is a solution that I come up with the builds on top of the standard JSON architecture, uses the preferred .Net Core encryption libraries, and is very DI friendly.

```
public static class IServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddProtectedConfiguration(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddDataProtection()
            .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\keys"))
            .ProtectKeysWithDpapi();

        return services;
    }

    public static IServiceCollection ConfigureProtected<TOptions>(this IServiceCollection services, IConfigurationSection section) where TOptions: class, new()
    {
        return services.AddSingleton(provider =>
        {
            var dataProtectionProvider = provider.GetRequiredService<IDataProtectionProvider>();
            section = new ProtectedConfigurationSection(dataProtectionProvider, section);

            var options = section.Get<TOptions>();
            return Options.Create(options);
        });
    }

    private class ProtectedConfigurationSection : IConfigurationSection
    {
        private readonly IDataProtectionProvider _dataProtectionProvider;
        private readonly IConfigurationSection _section;
        private readonly Lazy<IDataProtector> _protector;

        public ProtectedConfigurationSection(
            IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider,
            IConfigurationSection section)
        {
            _dataProtectionProvider = dataProtectionProvider;
            _section = section;

            _protector = new Lazy<IDataProtector>(() => dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector(section.Path));
        }

        public IConfigurationSection GetSection(string key)
        {
            return new ProtectedConfigurationSection(_dataProtectionProvider, _section.GetSection(key));
        }

        public IEnumerable<IConfigurationSection> GetChildren()
        {
            return _section.GetChildren()
                .Select(x => new ProtectedConfigurationSection(_dataProtectionProvider, x));
        }

        public IChangeToken GetReloadToken()
        {
            return _section.GetReloadToken();
        }

        public string this[string key]
        {
            get => GetProtectedValue(_section[key]);
            set => _section[key] = _protector.Value.Protect(value);
        }

        public string Key => _section.Key;
        public string Path => _section.Path;

        public string Value
        {
            get => GetProtectedValue(_section.Value);
            set => _section.Value = _protector.Value.Protect(value);
        }

        private string GetProtectedValue(string value)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return null;

            return _protector.Value.Unprotect(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Wire up your protected config sections like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    // Configure normal config settings
    services.Configure<MySettings>(Configuration.GetSection("MySettings"));

    // Configure protected config settings
    services.AddProtectedConfiguration();
    services.ConfigureProtected<MyProtectedSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("MyProtectedSettings"));
}
```

You can easily create encrypted values for your config files using a controller like this:

```
[Route("encrypt"), HttpGet, HttpPost]
public string Encrypt(string section, string value)
{
    var protector = _dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector(section);
    return protector.Protect(value);
}
```

Usage: 
`http://localhost/cryptography/encrypt?section=SectionName:KeyName&value=PlainTextValue`

Comment: I am leveraging this technique.  I get an encrypted value from the controller, but then when the protected section attempts to Unprotect, I get a cryptographic exception saying the payload is invalid. 

oops, hit enter too soon..

Does something special need to be done with the encrypt portion to relate it to the unprotect portion?

Comment: Looks like I am having a naming issue.  When I changed both the DataProtectors naming to "Test", it worked.  Something about my section names isn't working, but at least I found the issue.

Comment: I'm able to encrypt the connection string, but how to I decrypt it again during application startup ?

Comment: By default, a new key is regenerated every 90 days, so that the ciphertext in the configuration file will fail to decrypt again if it is not updated. Also,  ASP.NET Core generates different keys to encrypt data when it is running on different machines so it's not usable like this if your app is distributed.

Comment: I'm also curious, in what form are the secrets stored in PersistKeysToFileSystem specified path? If they are encrypted, then how?

Comment: Answering myself - ProtectKeysWithDpapi won't work on *nix machines - it's Windows specific. And PersistKeysToFileSystem alone secrets are encrypted with a raw key. There is even a warning in the XML file.

Comment: anybody knew whether or not DataProtectionAPI works in PCF? asking because the process is erroring out in accessing the machine key while decrypting.

Answer (score 21):

I didn't want to write a custom provider – way too much work. I just wanted to tap into JsonConfigurationProvider, so I figured out a way that works for me, hope it helps someone.

```
public class JsonConfigurationProvider2 : JsonConfigurationProvider
{
    public JsonConfigurationProvider2(JsonConfigurationSource2 source) : base(source)
    {
    }

    public override void Load(Stream stream)
    {
        // Let the base class do the heavy lifting.
        base.Load(stream);

        // Do decryption here, you can tap into the Data property like so:

         Data["abc:password"] = MyEncryptionLibrary.Decrypt(Data["abc:password"]);

        // But you have to make your own MyEncryptionLibrary, not included here
    }
}

public class JsonConfigurationSource2 : JsonConfigurationSource
{
    public override IConfigurationProvider Build(IConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        EnsureDefaults(builder);
        return new JsonConfigurationProvider2(this);
    }
}

public static class JsonConfigurationExtensions2
{
    public static IConfigurationBuilder AddJsonFile2(this IConfigurationBuilder builder, string path, bool optional,
        bool reloadOnChange)
    {
        if (builder == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(builder));
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("File path must be a non-empty string.");
        }

        var source = new JsonConfigurationSource2
        {
            FileProvider = null,
            Path = path,
            Optional = optional,
            ReloadOnChange = reloadOnChange
        };

        source.ResolveFileProvider();
        builder.Add(source);
        return builder;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really helpful neither does it increase the security a lot. In order to decrypt the data, you need the decryption key, which is within your application. So one attacker who gets on your server will have both, the configuration file and the application and can still easily decrypt your data. You should rather use the [DataProtection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/introduction?view=aspnetcore-2.1) for local or [Azure Key Valut](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault/) for azure applications.

Comment: These protect you even when your application / local files are stolen, because the private keys to decrypt (data protection) are marked as not-exportable (so an attacker can't easily steal them) and on azure key vault they are outside the application, so when someone copies your appsettings.json and application data from the server, he can't get the user secrets/credentials. The post here is nothing else than fake security (security by obscurity) and offers no protection at all

Comment: @Tseng You are correct, but this solution was made prior to when Asp.net Core 2 existed.

Comment: Both [Azure KeyVault](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault/1.0.0) (.NET Core 1.1)  and [DataProtection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Extensions/1.0.0) (.NET Core 1.0) where there for a long time, with dataprotection dating back to the rc versions of 1.0

Comment: DataProtection class isn't FIPS compliant, so if you're a government organization, try again.  From Microsoft: "meaning only classes that end in CryptoServiceProvider" or "Cng" can be used." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/fips-140-validation#id0eibac

Comment: @Tseng If an attacker owns your server, there's no difference in keeping your secrets in plain text or using Data Protection or Azure Key Vault because he can always do a memory dump of your app to retrieve the data, once your app gets it decrypted.

Comment: @VladRadu: Nowhere claimed it protects where attacker has full access to the server (i.e. can run code and admin/root priviledges). A lot of attacks however consists of unprotected path traversal attacks, i.e. allowing a person to read the configuration file or download the application binaries, but not executing code. In this cases Azure VaultKey does indeed protect your data. Not to speak its easier to manage in VaultKey. One change, affects all applications and instances, where encrypting values in appsettings require you to recompile/redeploy your app and encode its values first

Comment: @Tseng why can't we use an JsonConfigurationProvider2 and DataProtection together?

Comment: @ВладимирБереза No one say, you can't. Question is, does it makes sense. The elemental weakness of the the solution in this answer is, that the decryption key must be known to the application and if you don't use the data protection one, you have to store the decryption key within your binary or on easily accessible on the file system, so anyone who can access the file system can decode it, while data protection uses non-exportable keys. They may steal your appsettings, but the decryption key can't be stolen that way

Comment: @Tseng When we use the DataProtection and store the keys on the file system, we can also use some complicated function for calculating of purpose(dataProtector parameter). If we mask the function in obfuscated code than anyone cant't decrypt the data even if he steal binaries and keys.

Comment: @ВладимирБереза: Obfuscation is not fool-proof and can still be reversed with effort, the client has to do it anyway so a cracker can extract it. its on the same level as game DRM. If its executed on the client-side, so it can be cracked, just a matter of time and effort. With an external secrets provider such as azure vault, this can't happen in case the binaries are stolen

Comment: @Tseng How does Azure key vault can protect our keys from malefactor? If somebody has access to our server and our Dotnet app then he can steel the Client ID and X.509 certificate to access secrets stored in Azure Key Vault.

Comment: @ВладимирБереза Could you please learn to read, since I've mentioned it for the 5th time or so. When someone is able to get your program files, do not translate they have full access to your server or azure vault. It can be a badly protected share, then the user can download the files but still not access your azure vault. if its an docker image, someone could gain access to your docker registry and download the image which contains the secrets and the code. Or some badly protected blob storage or build pipeline.

Comment: All these are SOURCES where you can gain the program files and settings WITHOUT having access to your azure vault. If someone compromises your domain admin or azure domain account, its game over anyways, no matter what kind of security measure you have taken. Against all the cases above, azure vault protects your credentials, where a config file **DOES NOT**. Its all about **MINIMIZING** the attack surface and reducing the risk. If you don't get it, maybe let others handle security issues.

Comment: Also, no. If someone gets your key valut stuff, they can't connect to it, unless you have done bad job and somehow made allowed your keyvallt to be accessed from outside of your organizations subscription. By default you can't access key vault from outside of your azure organization

Answer (score 13):

I managed to create a custom JSON configuration provider which uses DPAPI to encrypt and decrypt secrets. It basically uses simple regular expressions that you can define to specify what parts of the JSON needs to be encrypted.

The following steps are performed:

1. Json file is loaded
2. Determine whether the JSON parts that match the given regular expressions are already encrypted (or not). This is done by base-64 decoding of the JSON part and verify whether it starts with the expected prefix **!ENC!**)
3. If not encrypted, then encrypt the JSON part by first using DPAPI and secondly add the prefix **!ENC!** and encode to base-64
4. Overwrite the unencrypted JSON parts with the encrypted (base-64) values in the Json file

> Note that the base-64 does not bring better security, but only hides the prefix **!ENC!** for cosmetic reasons. This is just a matter of taste of course ;)

This solution consists of the following classes:

1. **ProtectedJsonConfigurationProvider** class (= custom JsonConfigurationProvider)
2. **ProtectedJsonConfigurationSource** class (= custom JsonConfigurationSource)
3. **AddProtectedJsonFile()** extension method on the *IConfigurationBuilder* in order to simple add the protected configuration

Assuming the following initial **authentication.json** file:

```
{
    "authentication": {
        "credentials": [
            {
                user: "john",
                password: "just a password"
            },
            {
                user: "jane",
                password: "just a password"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Which becomes (sort of) the following after loading

```
{
    "authentication": {
        "credentials": [
            {
                "user": "john",
                "password": "IUVOQyEBAAAA0Iyd3wEV0R=="
            },
            {
                "user": "jane",
                "password": "IUVOQyEBAAAA0Iyd3wEV0R=="
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And assuming the following configuration class based on the json format

```
public class AuthenticationConfiguration
{
    [JsonProperty("credentials")]
    public Collection<CredentialConfiguration> Credentials { get; set; }
}

public class CredentialConfiguration
{
    [JsonProperty("user")]
    public string User { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Below the sample code:

```
//Note that the regular expression will cause the authentication.credentials.password path to be encrypted.
//Also note that the byte[] contains the entropy to increase security
var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddProtectedJsonFile("authentication.json", true, new byte[] { 9, 4, 5, 6, 2, 8, 1 },
        new Regex("authentication:credentials:[0-9]*:password"));

var configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();
var authenticationConfiguration = configuration.GetSection("authentication").Get<AuthenticationConfiguration>();

//Get the decrypted password from the encrypted JSON file.
//Note that the ProtectedJsonConfigurationProvider.TryGet() method is called (I didn't expect that :D!)
var password = authenticationConfiguration.Credentials.First().Password
```

> Install the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder package in order to get the configuration.GetSection("authentication").**Get<T>()** implementation

And finally the classes in which the magic happens :)

```
/// <summary>Represents a <see cref="ProtectedJsonConfigurationProvider"/> source</summary>
public class ProtectedJsonConfigurationSource : JsonConfigurationSource
{
    /// <summary>Gets the byte array to increse protection</summary>
    internal byte[] Entropy { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>Represents a <see cref="ProtectedJsonConfigurationProvider"/> source</summary>
    /// <param name="entropy">Byte array to increase protection</param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"/>
    public ProtectedJsonConfigurationSource(byte[] entropy)
    {
        this.Entropy = entropy ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(Localization.EntropyNotSpecifiedError);
    }

    /// <summary>Builds the configuration provider</summary>
    /// <param name="builder">Builder to build in</param>
    /// <returns>Returns the configuration provider</returns>
    public override IConfigurationProvider Build(IConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        EnsureDefaults(builder);
        return new ProtectedJsonConfigurationProvider(this);
    }

    /// <summary>Gets or sets the protection scope of the configuration provider. Default value is <see cref="DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser"/></summary>
    public DataProtectionScope Scope { get; set; }
    /// <summary>Gets or sets the regular expressions that must match the keys to encrypt</summary>
    public IEnumerable<Regex> EncryptedKeyExpressions { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>Represents a provider that protects a JSON configuration file</summary>
public partial class ProtectedJsonConfigurationProvider : JsonConfigurationProvider
{
    private readonly ProtectedJsonConfigurationSource protectedSource;
    private readonly HashSet<string> encryptedKeys = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    private static readonly byte[] encryptedPrefixBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("!ENC!");

    /// <summary>Checks whether the given text is encrypted</summary>
    /// <param name="text">Text to check</param>
    /// <returns>Returns true in case the text is encrypted</returns>
    private bool isEncrypted(string text)
    {
        if (text == null) { return false; }

        //Decode the data in order to verify whether the decoded data starts with the expected prefix
        byte[] decodedBytes;
        try { decodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(text); }
        catch (FormatException) { return false; }

        return decodedBytes.Length >= encryptedPrefixBytes.Length
            && decodedBytes.AsSpan(0, encryptedPrefixBytes.Length).SequenceEqual(encryptedPrefixBytes);
    }

    /// <summary>Converts the given key to the JSON token path equivalent</summary>
    /// <param name="key">Key to convert</param>
    /// <returns>Returns the JSON token path equivalent</returns>
    private string convertToTokenPath(string key)
    {
        var jsonStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        //Split the key by ':'
        var keyParts = key.Split(':');
        for (var keyPartIndex = 0; keyPartIndex < keyParts.Length; keyPartIndex++)
        {
            var keyPart = keyParts[keyPartIndex];

            if (keyPart.All(char.IsDigit)) { jsonStringBuilder.Append('[').Append(keyPart).Append(']'); }
            else if (keyPartIndex > 0) { jsonStringBuilder.Append('.').Append(keyPart); }
            else { jsonStringBuilder.Append(keyPart); }
        }

        return jsonStringBuilder.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>Writes the given encrypted key/values to the JSON oconfiguration file</summary>
    /// <param name="encryptedKeyValues">Encrypted key/values to write</param>
    private void writeValues(IDictionary<string, string> encryptedKeyValues)
    {
        try
        {
            if (encryptedKeyValues == null || encryptedKeyValues.Count == 0) { return; }

            using (var stream = new FileStream(this.protectedSource.Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                JObject json;

                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8, true, 4096, true))
                {
                    using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
                    {
                        json = JObject.Load(jsonTextReader);

                        foreach (var encryptedKeyValue in encryptedKeyValues)
                        {
                            var tokenPath = this.convertToTokenPath(encryptedKeyValue.Key);
                            var value = json.SelectToken(tokenPath) as JValue;
                            if (value.Value != null) { value.Value = encryptedKeyValue.Value; }
                        }
                    }
                }

                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream))
                {
                    using (var jsonTextWriter = new JsonTextWriter(streamWriter) { Formatting = Formatting.Indented })
                    {
                        json.WriteTo(jsonTextWriter);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format(Localization.ProtectedJsonConfigurationWriteEncryptedValues, this.protectedSource.Path), exception);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Represents a provider that protects a JSON configuration file</summary>
    /// <param name="source">Settings of the source</param>
    /// <see cref="ArgumentNullException"/>
    public ProtectedJsonConfigurationProvider(ProtectedJsonConfigurationSource source) : base(source)
    {
        this.protectedSource = source as ProtectedJsonConfigurationSource;
    }

    /// <summary>Loads the JSON data from the given <see cref="Stream"/></summary>
    /// <param name="stream"><see cref="Stream"/> to load</param>
    public override void Load(Stream stream)
    {
        //Call the base method first to ensure the data to be available
        base.Load(stream);

        var expressions = protectedSource.EncryptedKeyExpressions;
        if (expressions != null)
        {
            //Dictionary that contains the keys (and their encrypted value) that must be written to the JSON file
            var encryptedKeyValuesToWrite = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            //Iterate through the data in order to verify whether the keys that require to be encrypted, as indeed encrypted.
            //Copy the keys to a new string array in order to avoid a collection modified exception
            var keys = new string[this.Data.Keys.Count];
            this.Data.Keys.CopyTo(keys, 0);

            foreach (var key in keys)
            {
                //Iterate through each expression in order to check whether the current key must be encrypted and is encrypted.
                //If not then encrypt the value and overwrite the key
                var value = this.Data[key];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && expressions.Any(e => e.IsMatch(key)))
                {
                    this.encryptedKeys.Add(key);

                    //Verify whether the value is encrypted
                    if (!this.isEncrypted(value))
                    {
                        var protectedValue = ProtectedData.Protect(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value), protectedSource.Entropy, protectedSource.Scope);
                        var protectedValueWithPrefix = new List<byte>(encryptedPrefixBytes);
                        protectedValueWithPrefix.AddRange(protectedValue);

                        //Convert the protected value to a base-64 string in order to mask the prefix (for cosmetic purposes)
                        //and overwrite the key with the encrypted value
                        var protectedBase64Value = Convert.ToBase64String(protectedValueWithPrefix.ToArray());
                        encryptedKeyValuesToWrite.Add(key, protectedBase64Value);
                        this.Data[key] = protectedBase64Value;
                    }
                }
            }

            //Write the encrypted key/values to the JSON configuration file
            this.writeValues(encryptedKeyValuesToWrite);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Attempts to get the value of the given key</summary>
    /// <param name="key">Key to get</param>
    /// <param name="value">Value of the key</param>
    /// <returns>Returns true in case the key has been found</returns>
    public override bool TryGet(string key, out string value)
    {
        if (!base.TryGet(key, out value)) { return false; }
        else if (!this.encryptedKeys.Contains(key)) { return true; }

        //Key is encrypted and must therefore be decrypted in order to return.
        //Note that the decoded base-64 bytes contains the encrypted prefix which must be excluded when unprotection
        var protectedValueWithPrefix = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
        var protectedValue = new byte[protectedValueWithPrefix.Length - encryptedPrefixBytes.Length];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(protectedValueWithPrefix, encryptedPrefixBytes.Length, protectedValue, 0, protectedValue.Length);

        var unprotectedValue = ProtectedData.Unprotect(protectedValue, this.protectedSource.Entropy, this.protectedSource.Scope);
        value = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(unprotectedValue);
        return true;
    }

/// <summary>Provides extensions concerning <see cref="ProtectedJsonConfigurationProvider"/></summary>
public static class ProtectedJsonConfigurationProviderExtensions
{
    /// <summary>Adds a protected JSON file</summary>
    /// <param name="configurationBuilder"><see cref="IConfigurationBuilder"/> in which to apply the JSON file</param>
    /// <param name="path">Path to the JSON file</param>
    /// <param name="optional">Specifies whether the JSON file is optional</param>
    /// <param name="entropy">Byte array to increase protection</param>
    /// <returns>Returns the <see cref="IConfigurationBuilder"/></returns>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"/>
    public static IConfigurationBuilder AddProtectedJsonFile(this IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder, string path, bool optional, byte[] entropy, params Regex[] encryptedKeyExpressions)
    {
        var source = new ProtectedJsonConfigurationSource(entropy)
        {
            Path = path,
            Optional = optional,
            EncryptedKeyExpressions = encryptedKeyExpressions
        };

        return configurationBuilder.Add(source);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static IServiceCollection ConfigureProtected<TOptions>(this IServiceCollection services, IConfigurationSection section) where TOptions: class, new()
{
    return services.AddSingleton(provider =>
    {
        var dataProtectionProvider = provider.GetRequiredService<IDataProtectionProvider>();
        var protectedSection = new ProtectedConfigurationSection(dataProtectionProvider, section);

        var options = protectedSection.Get<TOptions>();
        return Options.Create(options);
    });
}
```

This method is correct

Comment: Is it FIPS compliant?

Comment: Can you share the working copy of it? for some reason i'm unable to make it work.

Answer (score -2):

Just a few clarifications to help avoid problems. When you encrypt a value, it's using the section as 'Purpose' (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/consumer-apis/purpose-strings?view=aspnetcore-2.2) When you get a 'Payload not valid' or something similar, it's likely that the purpose you used to encrypt it, differs from the purpose use to decrypt it. So, let's say I have a first level section in my appsettings.json named 'SecureSettings' and within it a connection string:

```
{
"SecureSettings": 
  {
    "ConnectionString":"MyClearTextConnectionString"
  }
}
```

To encrypt the value, I'd call: http://localhost/cryptography/encrypt?section=SecureSettings:ConnectionString&value=MyClearTextConnectionString

You may not want to keep an Encrypt controller in the app itself btw.

Comment: And you may not want to send the text to encrypt in the URL over http