# Encrypt connection string and other configuration settings in ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I am wondering how to encrypt configuration settings, especially connection string in ASP.Net Core app.

The configuration files are in json.

Answer (score 8):

With encryption, your options are to build a custom configuration provider that loads the encrypted data and decrypts accordingly.
You can check this SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36062670/asp-net-5-mvc-6-encrypted-configuration) covering the same topic.
That SO answer refers to [this](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html#writing-custom-providers) guide of the asp.net docs on how to create a custom provider configuration.

If encryption is not strictly necessary there is a dedicated page on asp.net documentation for safe storage of app secrets during development which you can read [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/app-secrets.html).
Please note that these do NOT use encryption and involve using environment variables and/or using the Secret Manager tool.