# .Net Core App continuous deployment

Tags: asp.net-core, continuous-deployment

I have a question about replacing my app related settings like connection string. I am wondering if environment specific appsettings.json is the right way to store the app settings? and if yes, how to secure production database password in connection string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET 5 / MVC 6 Encrypted Configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36062670/asp-net-5-mvc-6-encrypted-configuration)

Comment: Are you hosting the app on Azure? If so you could look at the appsettings environment variables on the server.

Comment: Thanks. I am hosting on Azure. Will Azure app settigns work with appsettings.json? if so, will it just work by matching key?