# ASP.NET Core - How to decrypt and use the encrypted configuration section?

Tags: c#, encryption, asp.net-core

I've followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50952785) and now I'm not sure how to get the correct values back and use them in the code.

This is the configuration section i would like to use:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "connString1": "CfDJ8P1kYd0KR1J........",
    "connString2": "CfDJ8P1kYd0KR1J........"
  }
```

And this is my Startup.cs file:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);


            services.AddProtectedConfiguration();

            services.ConfigureProtected<ProtectedConnectionStrings>(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));

            services.AddDbContext<MyDBContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings")["connString2"]));
.
.
.
```

But the values i get from the configuration are not decrypted.

Furthermore, the object returned from `Configuration.GetSection()` is a regular `ConfigurationSection` object (and not the custom `ProtectedConfigurationSection` object i have).

Are the encrypted values supposed to be stored in the `appsettings.json` file? or they are stored in the `key-....` file?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use DI to get unencrypted values from your service.

```
public class MySQLClass
{
    public MySQLClass(IOptions<ConnectionStrings> connectionStrings)
    {
        string unencryptedCS = connectionStrings.Value.connString1;
    }
}
```