# How to get Database Connection String from Environment Variable

Tags: asp.net-core

My environment variables:

```
"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" : "Development"
"DatabaseConnectionString" : "SomeConnectionString"
"ConnectionStrings:DatabaseConnectionString" : "SomeConnectionString"
"ConnectionStrings__DatabaseConnectionString" : "SomeConnectionString"
```

What I've tried in `Program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables();
var connString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseConnection");
var connString = builder.Configuration["DatabaseConnectionString"];
var connString = builder.Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DatabaseConnectionString"];
var connString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DatabaseConnectionString");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connString));
```

Everything gets null.

More than that, changing `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to "Staging" still gets "Development". What can I do?

I know about:

[How to correctly store connection strings in environment variables for retrieval by production ASP.Net Core MVC applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44931613/how-to-correctly-store-connection-strings-in-environment-variables-for-retrieval)

and

[How can I use a Windows environment variable in my .NET Core API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53527234/how-can-i-use-a-windows-environment-variable-in-my-net-core-api)

but it didn't help me.

Comment: Typically you'd manage your connection string in the `appsettings.json` file rather than an environment variable. You can achieve the same environment specific setup using `appsettings.{Environment}.json`.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have encountered the same problem.
First, use "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT" over "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" as said in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Second, with MS Visual Studio you need to restart it every time you change any environment variable.

Third, to make IIS read new enviroment values I had to restart the whole server.