# Where should we store a password inside our ASP.NET Core MVC web application?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, privacy

I am working on an ASP.NET Core MVC web application, and in my code, I am sending an e-mail using the Gmail SMTP server. To do so, I need to pass the username and password.

Currently I have the password in my code, but I am not sure what is the best place to store the password in an ASP.NET Core MVC app? For example in the `web.config` or in the database?

Comment: Have a look at this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36062670/encrypted-configuration-in-asp-net-core encrypting the configuration is the standard way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I would store it in the appsettings.json it is save from being browsed.

Comment: so you mean the appsettings.json will not be visible to public users (by public users i mean, users that do not have access to the source code)?