# Can we use the ASPNET_REGIIS command to encrypt sections of the appsettings.json as we do with the asp.net app.config

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, appsettings

When working with asp.net we can encrypt parts of the asp.net console application's app.config file by following these steps:-

1- Rename the app.config to web.config >> run this command >>

```
ASPNET_REGIIS -pef "<<customAppSettingsGroup>>/<<customAppSettings>>" "C:\projects\MSE\MSE\MSE"
```

2- Rename the web.config back to app.config....

Now inside asp.net core we do not have `app.config`, instead we have the `appsettings.json`.. so my question is if we can encrypt parts of the `appsettings.json` using the above approach? If the answer is No, then what are the approaches to encrypt sections of the `appsettings.json`?

Thanks

Comment: @RyanWilson you mean i can add app.config file to my .net core application?

Comment: yes. you can add any type of file you like. But since you are trying to encrypt/decrypt sections of it using the ASP.Net tool, I'm not sure that this will work for you. There are multiple posts on here about doing something similar to the appsettings.json file. [encrypted-configuration-in-asp-net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36062670/encrypted-configuration-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: @RyanWilson it is not clear what is the actual  replacement for `ASPNET_REGIIS ` in .net core?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is NO you should not use ASPNET_REGIIS anymore. Unless you want to decrypt it manually.

**For development environment**, you should use the Secret Manager tool
as described [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=windows)

Initialize

```
dotnet user-secrets init
```

Set a secret

```
dotnet user-secrets set "Movies:ServiceApiKey" "12345"
```

**For production environment**
the recommended approach is Azure vault

Assuming you have an Azure vault ready

Set your secrets

```
az keyvault secret set --vault-name {KEY VAULT NAME} --name "SecretName" --value "secret_value_1_prod"
az keyvault secret set --vault-name {KEY VAULT NAME} --name "Section--SecretName" --value "secret_value_2_prod"
```

Azure-hosted apps use this [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0#use-managed-identities-for-azure-resources)

If you host your app outside azure you must follow this [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0#use-application-id-and-x509-certificate-for-non-azure-hosted-apps)

PS: If your application won't load keys in runtime, only on start the free tier is more than enough.

There is a third option to create a custom provider as you can check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#custom-configuration-provider).

OR

[This article](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2019/09/26/decrypting-config-settings.aspx) from visual studio magazine is about a custom configuration provider with AES encryption

Fourth option:
If you are willing to use docker you can rely on the Docker Swarm secrets as shows in [this article](https://jack-vanlightly.com/blog/2017/9/26/api-series-part-4-docker-secrets)

Comment: i want to use a simpler approaches similar to the ASPNET_REGIIS .. so can i still use ASPNET_REGIIS inside asp.net core?

Comment: Not in the way you used it to. ASPNET_REGIIS is used as just an encryption tool it has no knowledge of the new appsetting.json structure, so If you are willing rename the file to encrypt and decrypt the whole file manually every time before your app runs. it's possible but not practical or safe. If you don't want to use Azure. Your best bet is a custom configuration provider check [this article](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2019/09/26/decrypting-config-settings.aspx)

Comment: Yeah I also believe writing your own configuration provider it's the thing that makes most sense. Azure keyvault is nice but not everyone is on that, also maybe you can't afford the vendor lock in.

Comment: @Alexrgs but i am not sure how i will integrate this encryption provider with my .net core application?

Comment: @johnGuit 
Once you have your custom config provider you should change your startup to use the new provider. something like this
  ` public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
  IConfigurationBuilder encryptingBuilder = 
          new ConfigurationBuilder()
                  .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                  .Add(new EncryptedConfigurationSource(key, iv))
                  .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
IConfiguration cfg = encryptingBuilder.Build();  `
you can use CyberChef to encrypt

Comment: @Alexrgs but using the ASPNET_REGIIS  i am able to encrypt and decrypt.. not sure if i can use the same approach ..

Comment: @johnGu unfortunately you cannot use ASPNET_REGIIS, your app have no idea how to decrypt your settings, as the settings(just a file) are read direct on the app. I should have been more clear on my answer.