# How can I access my secret key in any class with .NET 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, secret-key

I have a secret key in a secrets.json file that I would like to access to hide my ConnectionString in my Db Context class. I see a bunch of tutorials with previous versions of .NET but I am confused on how to get this to work so that I don't have to type in the actual string. Can anyone help me? I have already created the secrets.json file and have placed the values inside the file by setting it. I just need help with accessing that value in my context class.

Program.cs:

```html
using ItunesMVC;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

//Not sure if I am doing this right. Should this be here in my Program.cs? 
var itunesDBConnectionString = builder.Configuration["ConnectionStrings:itunesAppDB"];

var secretConfig = builder.Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").Get<Configuration>();
var secretVar = secretConfig.connectionString;

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

SearchCountContext.cs:

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;

namespace ItunesMVC
{
    public partial class ItunesSearchDBEntities : DbContext
    {
    
        //Not sure how I can access the secret key in this file.
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        
        public string ConnectionString { get; private set; }
        
        public ItunesSearchDBEntities(DbContextOptions<ItunesSearchDBEntities> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
#warning To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, you should move it out of source code. You can avoid scaffolding the connection string by using the Name= syntax to read it from configuration - see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131148. For more guidance on storing connection strings, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263.
                optionsBuilder.UseMySql("This is where I have my ConnectionString", Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ServerVersion.Parse("8.0.28-mysql"));
            }
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.UseCollation("utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci")
                .HasCharSet("utf8mb4");

            OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
        }

        partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
        
        public DbSet<SearchCount> SearchCounts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Configuration.cs:

```html
namespace ItunesMVC;

//Do I need to make this class to access my secret key?
public class Configuration
{
    public string connectionString { get; set; }
}
```

appsettings.json:

```html
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Comment: Also put the complete code of the `appsettings.json` file

Comment: Done, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your file should contain a section called `ConnectionStrings`, but it doesn't

Comment: Thats because I am trying to read the section from a secrets.json file as a secret key. I will be sharing this project with someone else so I would like to hide my ConnectionString in my secrets.json file but am not sure how to access it.

Comment: aha In order to access the items inside the secret, you don't need to do anything special during the development, and the access is the same as before, but after publication, you have to save it in the server's Environment variables. see this [storing-production-secrets-in-asp-net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40131672/storing-production-secrets-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: The problem I am having is that I am confused on how to access it without using Startup.cs since .NET 6 doesn't use it. Can you look at my code and see what I am missing in my SearchCountContext.cs or Program.cs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after installing  **Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql** package

in `program.cs` file

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();


builder.Services.AddDbContextPool<ItunesSearchDBEntities>(options =>
{
    var connetionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("itunesAppDB");
    options.UseMySql(connetionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connetionString));
});
```

and remove `OnConfiguring` method from `ItunesSearchDBEntities` class

Comment: Thank you!! If my secrets.json file looks like this `{
  "ConnectionStrings:itunesAppDB": "server=localhost,3306;database=itunesApp;user=root;password=#hi#"
}` would the name be "itunesAppDB" or "ConnectionStrings:itunesAppDB"?

Comment: You're welcome No, there is no need to change, write as I wrote above

Comment: Do you know why I need to use "itunesAppDB" and not "ConnectionStrings:itunesAppDB"? It is working with "itunesAppDB" like you said but how if the key is "ConnectionStrings:itunesAppDB"? I just want to understand it, thank you for all your help

Comment: Also, will using a secret key be bad for someone else that will run the project? Will they be able to run the project or do I need to make it optional with `.AddUserSecrets(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), optional: true, reloadOnChange: false)`?

Comment: The `GetConnectionString` method directly refers to the `ConnectionStrings` object in your`json` file, and it was created for this purpose. If you don't want to use this special method, you must write the entire connection address as below.

`builder.Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:itunesAppDB").Value;`

Comment: What if my key was `ConnectionString` without the s? Would it still work? So like `"ConnectionString:itunesAppDB"`

Comment: If you use the `GetConnectionString` method, it won't work, but you can still write it yourself

`builder.Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionString:itunesAppDB").Value;`